Alert in Javascript loaded from a local HTML in a WebView2 control not working
We have a Windows App written in C++ that was using a WebView control. I have updated it to use WebView2. All our old test cases successfully complete except for one. The test case that is failing loads a local HTML file. In the HTML there is a button with an onClick event. The onClick event simply calls window.alert to show that it has been pressed.
<script type="text/javascript">
function ButtonTouched()
{
   window.alert('Youtouchedthebutton!');
}  
</script>
<input type="button" value="Touch Me" onclick="ButtonTouched()"/> 

However, when I press the button no message is displayed. The onClick event is firing.
If I look in Developer tools, I see this message... "Failed to launch 'ms-appx-web:///UI/WebView/Resources/Blank.html?t=1&imb=1&data=@alert%20Youtouchedthebutton!' because the scheme does not have a registered handler".
The WebView control is initialized because I see mIsWebViewInitialized is true and this->webView->CoreWebView2 is not null.
   auto task = create_task( this->webView->EnsureCoreWebView2Async() );
   task.then( [this]() 
   { 
      mIsWebViewInitialized = true;
   }

Here is how I'm loading the HTML file...
void WebBrowser::NavigateToUrlWhenReady( Platform::String ^relativePath, Platform::String ^basePath )
{
   if ( this->webView->CoreWebView2 != nullptr )
   {
      this->webView->CoreWebView2->Settings->IsScriptEnabled = true;
      this->webView->CoreWebView2->SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
         "LRlocalfile",
         basePath,
         CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind::Allow );

      this->webView->Source = ref new Uri( "https://LRlocalfile/" + relativePath );
   }
   else
   {
      TRACE( "NavigateToUrlWhenReady: Unable to load local file in browser. CoreWebView2 not ready" );
   }
}

This HTML file works fine in Edge and Firefox.
Any suggestions on how the issue can be fixed ?
